# Изменение профиля пользователя самим пользователем Django

Tags: python, django

я новичок в Django, так что не судите строго. При создании веб-сайта для друга у меня возникла проблема: с изменением профиля пользователя самим пользователем, ошибок нет, но по итогу ничего не сохраняется. Заранее благодарю вас за вашу помощь.

views.py

```
@login_required
def update_user(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserChangeForm()
        if form.is_valid():
            user = CustomUser.objects.filter(id=pk)
            form.save()
            user.avatar = form.avatar
            user.description = form.description
            user.username = form.username
            user.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = CustomUserChangeForm()
    return render(request, 'main/edit_profile.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Текст вашего сообщения')
    answer_by = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='на какой комментарий вы хотите ответить?')
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Автор', related_name='author')
    created_add = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Создано')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('answer_by', kwargs={"answer_by": self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Комментарий'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Комментарии'


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos', blank=True, verbose_name='Аватар')
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Описание', blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('username', kwargs={"username_id": self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Пользователь'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Пользователи'
```

forms.py

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['username', 'password1', 'password2', 'email', 'description', 'avatar']
        widget = {
            'avatar': forms.ImageField,
            'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'password1': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'password2': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': "введите ваш никнейм"})
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': "введите пароль"})
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': "введите пароль ещё раз"})
        self.fields['description'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control', 'rows': 5, 'placeholder': "введите описание вашего профиля"})
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': "введите ваш адрес эл. почты"})

        for fieldname in ['username', 'password1', 'password2']:
            self.fields[fieldname].help_text = None

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['username', 'description', 'avatar']
        widget = {
            'avatar': forms.ImageField,
            'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomUserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': "введите ваш никнейм"})
        self.fields['description'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control', 'rows': 5, 'placeholder': "введите описание вашего профиля"})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как минимум не сохраняется потому что нечего сохранять. Попробуйте вот так, если нет других ошибок должно помочь:

```
@login_required
def update_user(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserChangeForm(request.POST, request.FILES) # Нужно передать, что сохранять. У  Вас просто пустая форма
        if form.is_valid():
            img = form.cleaned_data['avatar'] # я бы взял аватарку и проверил ее как минимум её размеры

            changed_user = form.save(commit=False) # сохранил форму в памяти
            changed_user.user = request.user # добавляем текущего пользователя
            changed_user.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = CustomUserChangeForm()
        return render(request, 'main/edit_profile.html', {'form': form})
```